# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object with pickle.load

Tags: python, pickle, generative-adversarial-network

I have a Question, I copied the code from Style-GAN in a jupyter notebook but doesn't work properly, this is the code that doesnt work:

```
# Initialize TensorFlow.
tflib.init_tf()

# Load pre-trained network.
#url = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1MEGjdvVpUsu1jB4zrXZN7Y4kBBOzizDQ' # karras2019stylegan-ffhq-1024x1024.pkl
#with dnnlib.util.open_url(url, cache_dir=config.cache_dir) as f:
f="./karras2019stylegan-ffhq-1024x1024.pkl"
with open(f, 'rb') as pickle_file:
    _G, _D, Gs = pickle.load(pickle_file)
        # _G = Instantaneous snapshot of the generator. Mainly useful for resuming a previous training run.
        # _D = Instantaneous snapshot of the discriminator. Mainly useful for resuming a previous training run.
        # Gs = Long-term average of the generator. Yields higher-quality results than the instantaneous snapshot.
```

The problem is in

```
 _G, _D, Gs = pickle.load(pickle_file)
```

I have this Error: `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object`

I don't know why doesnt work, because I use the same code but in a .py and its works.

Anybody knows why doesn't work?

this is the repo:https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan

Comment: How was the object packed and saved in the first place?

Comment: Try `print(repr(pickle.load(pickle_file)))`. You are expecting a list of 3 values but are getting an integer.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I don't know, I only downloaded the .pkl to my pc

Comment: @tdelaney this is the output: 119547037146038801333356

and in the another .py file( thats works) i have this ouput :(<dnnlib.tflib.network.Network object at 0x7f946fe8a2b0>, <dnnlib.tflib.network.Network object at 0x7f93b06a9e80>, <dnnlib.tflib.network.Network object at 0x7f9380751eb8>)

Comment: @TomaateTip your `.pkl` file only contains a single `int`. Either you downloaded the wrong file or you are doing something else wrong.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli but in the .py works and is the same code and the same file

Comment: @TomaateTip - Whatever created that pickle file wrote a single large integer. You are expecting 3 things `_G, _D, Gs`. Either the writer or your code has the wrong data.

Comment: @TomaateTip I really doubt that it's both the *same* code and the *same* file. That's simply not possible.

Comment: @tdelaney 

I found the error, you are right, I copied the file, but it didn't copy well, I tried again, and it works! :)

Comment: @MarcoBonelli

I found the error, you are right, I copied the file, but it didn't copy well, I tried again, and it works! :)